# How to change the theme of Person.aspx in SharePoint My Sites

Tags: css, sharepoint, themes

I have my custom theme working everywhere except for the profile page for users under My Sites, which is the Person.aspx page. Any thoughts on how to apply the theme to this page? Or even just hard coding custom styling to it?

Thanks,
Kale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my solution for this issue. Assume your profile page URL http://sitename/Person.aspx
Enter the below url on IE and login http sitename/_layouts/settings.aspx

The Page (_layouts/settings.aspx) may requires admin privileges. Once you login then you'll get the option to change theme and other features. That's it.

Comment: This solution worked. Haven't seen it posted anywhere else, thank you Venkatesh!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that person.aspx is in a completely different site collection to the rest of the pages in the users site. You need to apply the theme separately to the mysite host site.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to use a Solution Package to push a feature containing the master pages/page layouts/styles to a site collection. That way you simply activate the feature at each site collection...e.g one for your Intranet and one for your MySites Site collection.

Answer (score 1):

Hard coding custom style can be done by replacing the Person.aspx page inside of the MySite Site Definition, however this is not a recommended practice.

[Here](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/mirjam/archive/2008/02/22/customizing-the-my-site-look-and-feel.aspx) is a different approach that might work for you, just depends on how far you have gotten with MySite rollout.